# Цикл с нечетным порядком элементов а не результата элементов в java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте Есть такое условие.

```
a = 1, b = 5
for (x = a; x <= b; x = x + h)
```

Интервал равен от `х_a` до `x_b` нужно что бы складывались нечетные икcы в этом интервале (`х1 + х3 + х5 + x_n` - нечетный)

Например `х1=2, х2=4, х3=6, x4=8, x5=12` (после равно это результат этой формулы `x=x+h`)  , нужно сложить нечетные `х1+х3+х5` , проверить сам порядок `х` а не его ответ. Ответ должен получиться если взять этот пример `20`. (т.к. `2+6+12`).

Надеюсь правильно объяснил.
Спасибо всем уделившим внимание

Comment: Выложите попытки решить задачу и мы поможем дойти до правильного решения! :)

Comment: я только знаю как проверить ответ  x на нечетность, а сам х не могу представить как проверить и написать

Comment: Выложите код, как вы хотя бы это делаете и мы подскажем как нужно

Comment: вообще не могу представить, if x%2==0  так проверяю сам результат икса на четность, а как проверить не результат икса а сам икс что он идет четным номером я не могу описать

Comment: А почему x5 = 12? Вы не ошиблись? 2, 4, 6, 8, 10?? h = 2 - шаг

Comment: @Mobsman я подправил ответ. Проверьте

Comment: ошибся, суть сложить нечетные х  , тоесть нечетные х с их результатом, результат не проверяется на нечетность, только сам порядок следования х

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно приведу и свой пример, то как я понял ваше условие.

`a` и `b` это промежуток, а `h` это шаг изменения `x` на промежутке.

И нужно найти сумму элементов на нечетных позициях.

```
int a = 0, b = 2, sum = 0;
double h = 0.5;

//Сам x (не порядок)
double x = h;
//i - порядок икса
//Увеличиваем порядок каждую итерацию на 1 и проверяем, чтобы он был нечетным
//А сам x увеличиваем каждую итерацию на нужный нам шаг h
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++, x += h) {
    //Если порядок нечетный
    if (i % 2 == 1)
        sum += x;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Ответ программы: `1`

```
 0   1   2
0.5  1  1.5 => sum = 1
```

Comment: я ошибся, вот так правильней а=0 b=2 h=0.5  , я в том примере хотел обьяснить смысл чего я хочу

Comment: Да с такими условиями только решать задачи

Comment: Все правильно, спасибо большое. Всех благ вам

Comment: @Mobsman тогда `h` нужно сделать вещественным числом. Подправил овтет

Comment: @Mobsman если мой ответ помог вам, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева. Удачи :)

Answer (score 0):

Что то такое думаю.

```
a = 1, b = 5
sum = 0
for (x = a; x <= b; x = x + h) {
 if(((x-a)/h)%2 == 0) sum += x;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Не много изменил код. С суммированием понятно. Небольшая загвоздка с условием. Значит вам нужны нечётные причем считать вы начинаете с 1.

x-а даст вам сколько h вы добавили к х. Делим на h получаем множитель. Нужно проверить его на четность поскольку вы считаете с 1.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что вопрос не совсем корректный. Вам нужно именно с теми двумя строчками кода что-то выкрутить?
Если задача заключается в том, что дается какой-то интервал и нужно найти сумму всех его нечетных значений, то это можно решить с помощью потока данных.

```
    int positionA = 1;
    int positionB = 5;
    
    int result =
    IntStream
        .range(positionA, positionB+1)
        .filter(x -> x%2==1)
        .sum();
```